# How to configure RabbitMQ for message persistence in Docker swarm?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-swarm

How can I configure RabbitMQ to retain messages on node restart in docker swarm?

I've marked the queues as durable and I'm setting the message's delivery mode to 2. I'm mounting /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia to a persistent volume. I've docker exec'd to verify that rabbitmq is indeed creating files in said folder, and all seems well. Everything works in my local machine using docker-compose.

However, when the container crashes, docker swarm creates a new one, and this one seems to initialize a new Mnesia database instead of using the old one. The database's name seems to be related to the container's id. It's just a single node, I'm not configuring any clustering.

I haven't changed anything in rabbitmq.conf, except for the cluster_name, since it seemed to be related to the folder created, but that didn't solve it.

Relevant section of the docker swarm configuration:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=cookie
      - RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
      - rabbitmq-conf:/etc/rabbitmq
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==foomachine
```

Comment: In docker swarm, volumes are local to the node where your container runs, like with any other docker engine running anywhere else. If your containers switches node, it creates a new volume. There are several solutions to implement shared volumes (NFS, EFS, sshfs, glusterfs...) but they don't work out of the box and I'm not quite sure I would use them for a message queue system which main awaited characteristics are to be fast and reliable...

Comment: No, no, it's using the same volume. I've double checked and the placement constraint should guarantee it.

Comment: You can either fight with RABBITMQ_NODENAME and RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR, OR you could just try something like: `hostname: {{.Node.Hostname}}` to force a consistent hostname between runs of the container.